# Minimal C library with only Linux system calls

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I'm working on embedded systems using Linux as operating system. Those systems don't include dynamic linker, so all libraries must be included statically. To ensure small binary sizes I need an small C library. I know that there are many options, but my code only uses system calls, no standard C library calls, POSIX or any other extensions. Using a complete and general purpose library is an overkill.

I can write this library in assembly, but my target hardware isn't homogeneous. I need some level of portability between architectures (ARM, i386 and x86_64) and versions of Linux kernels.

Are there any small footprint C library that only includes Linux system calls?

Comment: If you link statically, only those object members useful for your program are linked, not all the library

Comment: See also wikipage on [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations). Consider [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/)

Comment: In the previous century (and also in SVR4), there used to be some `libsys`; but I believe it disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Pure system calls are what you're doing in ASM, the finished product is architecture specific by nature. It's the C/POSIX part that abstracts them via defined interfaces

Unless you mean you don't require a full POSIX user-land?
POSIX itself is large, and the lower parts cover the type of thing your asking for.  For example, the specified headers in sys/*.h.

You can get a mini library for just this specific purpose, for embedded systems.  Have you looked at [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/)?  OR if you want to go even lower, check out klibc.

Remember those standard functions are either bootstrapped, and can be written in C itself (with no included stdlib), or system specific wrappers.  You may be able to find what you looking for by reviewing the code of those projects.

Comment: I only need Linux (kernel) system calls C interface. I want an abstraction library so I don't have to worry about ABI and architecture specific things. I also want a project maintained by a third to simplify maintenance: I have enough work with my application to worry about interface to the underlying system.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a preexisting standard library. Since you're linking statically, you'll only get what you need. Here is an example using musl for x86_64 and ARM:

```
[~/ellcc/examples/write] dev% cat main.c
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                 

int main()                                                                                          
{                                                                                                   
    write(1, "hello world\n", sizeof("hello world\n"));                                             
}                                                                                                   
[~/ellcc/examples/write] dev% make x86_64-linux-eng
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rich/ellcc/examples/write'                                       
Compiling main.c                                                                                    
Linking write                                                                                       
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rich/ellcc/examples/write'                                        
[~/ellcc/examples/write] dev% ./write
hello world                                                                                         
[~/ellcc/examples/write] dev% size write                                                            
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename                                                    
   1617      32     568    2217     8a9 write                                                       
[~/ellcc/examples/write] dev% make arm-linux-engeabihf                                              
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rich/ellcc/examples/write'                                       
rm -f *.o write write.bin write.log elkconfig.ld                                                    
Compiling main.c                                                                                    
Linking write                                                                                       
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rich/ellcc/examples/write'                                        
[~/ellcc/examples/write] dev% ./write
hello world                                                                                         
[~/ellcc/examples/write] dev% size write
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename                                                    
   3282      16     376    3674     e5a write                                                       
[~/ellcc/examples/write] dev%
```

Comment: I will get what I need plus any other code inside same compilation unit. My tests show that linking against GNU libc results in a significantly larger binary that linking against uclib, calling only Linux system calls.

Comment: musl is very good at minimizing what gets pulled in. You can even use POSIX stuff, like pthread_create() without too much overhead.

Comment: I checked musl and dietlibc source code and both pack one function per compilation unit, so there aren't unused code linked to output binary. However, both include useless (on my application) initialization code on their `_start` function (compiled inside `crt0.o` on some libraries). I will accept this solution until I find something that best fit my needs. Thanks.

Comment: You must be working in a very tightly constrained environment if 2-3K of code to initialize the library is too much. Especially when the library gives the ability to use higher level functions in the future if you need them.